# Отображение изображения из файла в PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

В ListBox добавляется музыка. Нужно чтобы когда пользователь выберет/выделит музыку в ListBox и после нажмет на Button, то в PictureBox должна отобразится обложка альбома этой музыки если она есть. У многих же композиций привязана обложка к самому файлу.

Comment: Попробуйте [TagLib#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib/).

Answer (score 0):

Есть метод [`PictureBox.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f6ak7was(v=vs.110).aspx).

Просто подаешь ему на вход путь к файлу и все.

Comment: Думаю, ОП хочет извлечь изображение из медиа-файла (типа mp3). А их туда, [оказывается](http://www.richardfarrar.com/embedding-album-art-in-mp3-files/), можно насовать кучу.